# I get ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is as below and I get an error,

> invalid relational operator

on line4.

```
select  SERIAL 
  from base.base_voucher_used b 
 where b.dw_date_key 
   and serial in (select serial 
                    from base.base_voucher_used a 
                   where DW_DATE_KEY 
                   group by serial 
                  having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified any condition in your `where clause` for the column `dw_date_key`.

I assume you want to select those `serial`, where the count is greater than 1. If so, only one query suffices.

```
select serial 
  from base.base_voucher_used a 
 where DW_DATE_KEY = 1  --add your condition here
 group by serial 
having count(*) > 1
```